# How to retrieve data from golang-map

Tags: json, go

I put my json data on Unmarsha1. How can i retrieve data like

```
  log.Print(b["beat"]["name"])
```

but how can I retrieve data like 
     log.Print(b["beat"]["name"]) --> fail to get data

My Code is like following:

```
var b map[string]interface{}

data := []byte(`
    {"foo":1,"beat":{"@timestamp":"2016-10-27T12:02:00.352Z","name":"localhost.localdomain","version":"6.0.0-alpha1"}}
`)

err := json.Unmarshal(data, &b)

if err != nil{
    fmt.Println("error: ", err)
}
log.Print(b)
log.Print(b["beat"]["name"])
```

Thank You

Comment: Well, the type of `b` is `map[string]interface{}` so `b["beat"]` is of type `interface{}` which should make it clear what to do from here on. If not: Take the Tour of Go once more(you did it twice already?), especially chapter 14ff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got error cause `b["beat"]` is not a map, so you can't use `b["beat"]["name"]`.

you declare `b` with `map[string]interface{}`, so `b` can use like `b["beat"]`,but `b["beat"]` is a value of interface type, so it can use like `b["beat"]["name"]`, for this you can add these line.

```
var m map[string]interface{}
m = b["beat"].(map[string]interface{})
log.Println(m["name"])
```

it turn type for `b["beat"]` from interface to map.

For more:

1. you can create a struct for this json string,and then you can get value from your struct with `.` symbol. like the Unmarshal exsample in https://www.dotnetperls.com/json-go
2. there is a package [go-simplejson](https://github.com/bitly/go-simplejson) can get json value easily.

Hope this can help you...